WinHttpCrackUrl function gets wrong nScheme
After running the above code, the output result is not https, but Other(2).
Why does this happen?
The execution environment is Windows 10 (64-bit). The code is compiled as C++14.
#include <windows.h>
#include <WinInet.h>
#include <winhttp.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#pragma comment(lib, "wininet.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "Winhttp.lib")

int main() {
    std::wstring gitHubApiUrl = L"https://api.github.com";

    URL_COMPONENTSW urlComponents = {};
    urlComponents.dwStructSize = sizeof(URL_COMPONENTSW);

    // Buffers for host and path
    wchar_t hostName[256] = {};
    wchar_t urlPath[1024] = {};
    urlComponents.lpszHostName = hostName;
    urlComponents.dwHostNameLength = ARRAYSIZE(hostName);
    urlComponents.lpszUrlPath = urlPath;
    urlComponents.dwUrlPathLength = ARRAYSIZE(urlPath);

    // Call WinHttpCrackUrl
    if (!WinHttpCrackUrl(gitHubApiUrl.c_str(), static_cast<DWORD>(gitHubApiUrl.size()), 0, &urlComponents)) {
        std::wcerr << L"Failed to parse URL. Error: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    // Output parsed components
    std::wcout << L"Scheme: ";
    switch (urlComponents.nScheme) {
    case INTERNET_SCHEME_HTTP: std::wcout << L"HTTP"; break;
    case INTERNET_SCHEME_HTTPS: std::wcout << L"HTTPS"; break;
    default: std::wcout << L"Other (" << urlComponents.nScheme << L")"; break;
    }
    std::wcout << std::endl;

    std::wcout << L"Host Name: " << urlComponents.lpszHostName << std::endl;
    std::wcout << L"URL Path: " << urlComponents.lpszUrlPath << std::endl;
    return 0;
}


I can't see how this could happen. INTERNET_SCHEME_HTTPS is defined as (2), so it doesn't make sense that the default arm is executed for a value of 2. Can you show a [mcve]?

Cannot repro, it prints Scheme: HTTPS for me.

I found the reason, the reason for this problem is so weird. When  #include <WinInet.h> is above #include <winhttp.h>, Other(2) will be output.
Otherwise, if #include <winhttp.h> is above #include <WinInet.h>, https will be output normally, because the INTERNET_SCHEME enumeration is defined in both header files.
Code:
#include <windows.h>
#include <WinInet.h>
#include <winhttp.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#pragma comment(lib, "wininet.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "Winhttp.lib")

int main() {
    std::wstring gitHubApiUrl = L"https://api.github.com";

    URL_COMPONENTSW urlComponents = {};
    urlComponents.dwStructSize = sizeof(URL_COMPONENTSW);

    // Buffers for host and path
    wchar_t hostName[256] = {};
    wchar_t urlPath[1024] = {};
    urlComponents.lpszHostName = hostName;
    urlComponents.dwHostNameLength = ARRAYSIZE(hostName);
    urlComponents.lpszUrlPath = urlPath;
    urlComponents.dwUrlPathLength = ARRAYSIZE(urlPath);

    // Call WinHttpCrackUrl
    if (!WinHttpCrackUrl(gitHubApiUrl.c_str(), static_cast<DWORD>(gitHubApiUrl.size()), 0, &urlComponents)) {
        std::wcerr << L"Failed to parse URL. Error: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    // Output parsed components
    std::wcout << L"Scheme: ";
    switch (urlComponents.nScheme) {
      case INTERNET_SCHEME_HTTP: std::wcout << L"HTTP"; break;
      case INTERNET_SCHEME_HTTPS: std::wcout << L"HTTPS"; break;
      default: std::wcout << L"Other (" << urlComponents.nScheme << L")"; break;
    }
    std::wcout << std::endl;

    std::wcout << L"Host Name: " << urlComponents.lpszHostName << std::endl;
    std::wcout << L"URL Path: " << urlComponents.lpszUrlPath << std::endl;
    return 0;
}


INTERNET_SCHEME_HTTPS is declared in the INTERNET_SCHEME enum of wininet.h with a value of 4. winhttp.h then re-defines INTERNET_SCHEME_HTTPS with a value of 2 using a #define. WinInet and WinHTTP should not be mixed together.

INTERNET_SCHEME_HTTPS value is in fact 2 as defined in winhttp.h.
Your code is probably using wininet.h value which is 4.
Make sure you don't mix both, both WinINet and WinHTTP serve the same purpose but are quite different: WinINet vs. WinHTTP

have Microsoft not heard of the ODR?

Macros are not definitions.

@AlanBirtles - They could have avoided that since WinINet (developped for Internet Explorer) predates WinHTTP, which was developped precisely to avoid WinINet lack of server-side capabilities... but they probably didn't think someone would reference both technologies (which is indeed unexpected)

@3CxEZiVlQ but if you include the winhttp.h macros before the wininet.h enum it changes the definition of the enum

@AlanBirtles Of course it does, but that is not an ODR violation. It's a preprocessor macro redefinition, and the compiler will issue a warning. Microsoft have no agency over developers ignoring compiler diagnostics.

You're absolutely right and that's exactly why, I've put the full code below.
